# Ubuntu 16.04 Wifi disconnecting

Tags: ubuntu, wifi, surface

after upgrading to 16.04 my wifi randomly drops. Often a few minutes after startup but sometimes after multiple hours. I am dualbooting Ubuntu on Microsofts Surface Pro 4.

Output of "lspci -knn | grep Wireless":

```
02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Marvell Technology Group Ltd. 88W8897 [AVASTAR] 802.11ac Wireless [11ab:2b38]
```

Output of "lspci":

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Sky Lake Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 08)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Sky Lake Integrated Graphics (rev 07)
00:05.0 Multimedia controller: Intel Corporation Sky Lake Imaging Unit (rev 01)
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake Gaussian Mixture Model
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 21)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem (rev 21)
00:14.3 Multimedia controller: Intel Corporation Device 9d32 (rev 01)
00:15.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller (rev 21)
00:15.1 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller (rev 21)
00:15.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller (rev 21)
00:15.3 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller (rev 21)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI (rev 21)
00:16.4 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Device 9d3e (rev 21)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port (rev f1)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9d18 (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP LPC Controller (rev 21)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PMC (rev 21)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21)
01:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd NVMe SSD Controller (rev 01)
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Marvell Technology Group Ltd. 88W8897 [AVASTAR] 802.11ac Wireless
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to U&L , to see the kernel module in use please update with the output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2`

Comment: @GAD3R: `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2`  won't generate an output. what does this mean?

When i startup in windows and look up the network adapters these are shown:
Network adapters:
Marvell AVASTAR Wireless-AC Network Controller;
VMware Virtual Ethernet Adapter for VMnet1;
VMware Virtual Ethernet Adapter for VMnet8;

Comment: `lspci -knn` and see the  `Kernel driver in use: ??` and `Kernel modules: ?? ??`

Comment: @GAD3R: `Kernel driver in use: mwifiex_pcie` and `Kernel modules: mwifiex_pcie`

Comment: from Grub menu , select  the advanced option of Ubuntu then try to boot an old kernel

Comment: @GAD3R: In the grub menu only 3 options are offered:
`Ubuntu with Linux 4.10.00-28-generic ` and then two of the same version with the addition of `(upstart)` and `(generic)` . I tried all and connecting still dropped, how do i load additional older kernels to the grub and which one do you recommend.

Answer (score 0):

After reinstalling the system on Ubuntu 14.04.05 it works.